# When current flows, Is there any potential difference?

Tags: voltage, batteries, current, wire, charge

there are electrons that can move, and protons that can’t move. Then when current flow exists, does electrons that can move move? How can I explain this phenomenon? If it is true, how can I explain this picture? (Sorry, I'm not good at English, )[image]

Comment: what does the title have to do with the question?

Comment: nobody says there aren't "new" electrons coming from the battery. There's no phenomenon to be explained here.

Comment: then I want to know how current flows?  (I thought direct moving of charge makes current flows)

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: @chu Could you explain me the principle that current flows?

Comment: Current will flow through a 'perfect' conductor without requiring a pd across that conductor. It's merely a pathway. We assume this all the time in circuit diagrams - two junctions are assumed to be at the same voltage if they are connected by a wire.

Comment: I learned that the charge moves by the principle of V=ED. Then does this principle work in the wire situation? If this is right I can't understand the moving of the charge in the wire. When the wire's registance is 0(ideal wire i mean) and the current flows, then the electrons are not moving by the principle V=ED?

Answer (score 1):

Entering into the world of super-conductivity things get decidedly odd.

In your case, with a superconducting wire across the battery, as you envision, measuring the voltage across any two points will yield a zero value since the resistance is also zero. This however, does not preclude the passing of current. Just as if it were a zero ohm jumper in a conventional circuit, you would not be able to measure any volts across it even when you know there is a current flowing.

In theory, with an ideal battery, the current would be infinite in the circuit you showed in order to obtain the battery voltage. However, in reality the battery has some resistance so you would be limited to that amount of current.

Of course, getting the battery to work at superconducting temperatures would be a trick all on it's own.

Answer (score 1):

The process of "charging" a superconducting magnet is much like the battery example above. A current is forced through the superconducting coil by an external source in series with some resistance. With a voltage source, current will increase more-or-less linearly with time until something happens- either the current exceeds the critical current of the weakest part of the coil causing the wire in the coil to go normal (resistive), or it levels off because of the resistance, or you short the coil terminals out with a superconducting switch (the preferred outcome). There will be a potential difference across the resistance. Before and after the switch closes there will be no potential difference across the coil.

After the current has been set up, the (now shorted) source can be removed and the current will continue to circulate indefinitely provided the critical current is not exceeded (it varies with temperature and magnetic field, for example).

Comment: I learned that the charge moves by the principle of V=ED. Then does this principle work in the wire situation? If this is right I can't understand the moving of the charge in the wire. When the wire's registance is 0(ideal wire i mean) and the current flows, then the electrons are not moving by the principle V=ED?   I want to know why there's no potential difference between V1 and V2

Comment: You have a circuit that is part superconducting (the superconducting wire- say lead or Nb at 4K) and part not (the battery and the wires from the battery). If the battery is  suddenly connected a voltage will appear across the superconducting wire and the resistive wire- the voltage across the superconducting wire will become negligibly small over time- the time constant is L/R where R is the resistance of the wire and internal resistance of the battery. The terminal current is V/R. As to *why* current keeps flowing if you short the SC ring- it's a quantum phenomenon. 1/2

Comment: 2/2 but you can also consider energy conservation.. if the energy stored in the flux is not to change the current must keep flowing. Since R=0 there is no mechanism for energy loss and the current must flow or energy would not be conserved.

Comment: 3/2 @dongho Even a straight piece of wire has some inductance. A few mm of wire has ~1nH inductance, which is actually quite a significant amount in some circumstances.

Comment: Is it different that V in V=Ed and V in V=IR? If I use V=IR, I understand your answer that R=0, so V=0. But when I use V=Ed, 'E' and 'd' are both exist not 0. So V is not 0. I can't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

to see a voltage difference between V1 and V2 you would need to cut the wire between them.

Comment: But then there would be no current flow - and that was the question. In any case, you wouldn't have to cut the wire - just file it thinner and thinner so that the resistance increases. I think you need an edit.